# Combine regexp_extract and regexp_replace to mask numbers in pyspark dataframe column

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a PySpark DataFrame, `df` like so:

```
|-----|-------|
|index|address|
|-----|-------|
|1|123 Apple Street|
|2|123-45-6789 Broad Street|
|-----|-------|
```

My regex pattern `r"\d{3}-\d{2)-\d{4}|\d{3} \d{2) \d{4}"` will filter down row 2. However, I need to mask the match, and it has to be a 1:1 match. So, in the above example instead of `X Broad Street` the updated value should be `XXX-XX-XXXX Broad Street`. 
Like so:

```
|-----|-------|
|index|address|
|-----|-------|
|1|123 Apple Street|
|2|XXX-XX-XXXX Broad Street|
|-----|-------|
```

I have tried nesting a `regex_replace` call over a `regexp_extract` call like so:

```
regexp_replace(regexp_extract(df["address"], "\d{3}-\d{2)-\d{4}|\d{3} \d{2) \d{4}", 0), "\d", "X")
```

However, I get an error which basically states I am not passing a string or string-like object to the outer regexp_replace function.

Is there a way to combine `regexp_replace` and `regexp_extract` functions to update the substring in place?

Comment: Can you post your desired output?

Comment: I am expecting my example value ```|2|123-45-6789 Broad Street|``` to become ```|2|XXX-XX-XXXX Broad Street|```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this approach.

```
        from pyspark.sql import functions as F

        df = sc.parallelize([
            (1, "123 Apple Street"), (2 ,"123-45-6789 Broad Street")
        ]).toDF(["index", "address"])

        df.show(truncate = False)

      +-----+------------------------+
      |index|address                 |
      +-----+------------------------+
      |1    |123 Apple Street        |
      |2    |123-45-6789 Broad Street|
      +-----+------------------------+

        df2 = df.withColumn("address", F.when(F.col('address').rlike("\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}|\d{3} \d{2} \d{4}"), F.regexp_replace(F.col('address'),r'\d','X')).otherwise(F.col('address')))

        df2.show(truncate=False)



        +-----+------------------------+
        |index|address                 |
        +-----+------------------------+
        |1    |123 Apple Street        |
        |2    |XXX-XX-XXXX Broad Street|
        +-----+------------------------+
```